# Install Ubuntu 23.04 surface tablets

Tags: touchscreen

Installed Ubuntu 23.04 on Surface Go 3 and everything works.
Installed Ubuntu 23.04 on Surface Pro 7 no touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the custom kernel maintained by the [linux-surface](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) project.

You can find the installation instructions [here](/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#debian--ubuntu).

[Here](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix) is the list of supported features.